# Running Script Message Before Header in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, message, destroy

I am trying to display this script message before the PHP destroys the session, although I'm struggling to understand how to make this work.

```
if($query_run)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Account Deleted") </script>'; 
    // Unset all of the session variables.
    $_SESSION = array();
    // Destroy the session
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: You can echo anything before `header()` for it to work FYI. You may want to do the redirect in javascript.